# Does Visual Studio's [Add Service Reference] an option for Data Contracts Only?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datacontract, service-reference, svcutil.exe

I am trying to add a service reference to my C#-project. The service reference points to an WSDL. But I only want the Data Contract classes. I do not need the Service contract classes/interface (in this project file).

Using "svcutil.exe" I can use the "/datacontractonly" option. How can I do the same from Visual Studio?

I have been searching in:

- The [Add Service Reference] dialog
- The Reference.svcmap

So far no luck. Does anyone know a way to make Visual Studio only import the Data Contract, without several command line utilities.

Comment: Why are you keen to avoid using command-line programs for codegen? I'd argue that you should _prefer_ `svcutil.exe` because you can more easily include it in MSBuild and CI/CD, whereas "Add Service Reference" is not automatable... (and you might have noticed that since .NET Core came out the entire ecosystem is shifting towards command-line tools that run separately from IDEs precisely for that reason).

Comment: @Dai: I prefer a good user interface, since it removes a lot of extra typing and clicks. Preferring command line utilities is i.m.o. the same as preferring notepad to write your code. So I am using VS as my toolbox and try to use as much integration stuff as it offers. As long as it supports certain features. Hence my question.